# phpmyadmin always logout instantly after login

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, logout

I tried to to increase cookie time for phpmyadmin, but now I have this strange behaviour: anytime I login, I see the databases list and instantly I get logged off by the system, with this message:

```
No activity within 0 seconds; please log in again
```

Note the "0" seconds.
What I did is:

- `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 1440;` in the config.inc.php phpmyadmin file
- `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440` in the php.ini file

Comment: Did you restarted the services ?

Comment: yes, I restarted apache2

Comment: Make sure you delete the old cookies from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your php.ini file and set the following variable value in it:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

After that, restart your server.